Regex: Replace all empty spaces between
Replace all empty spaces between  and first word, from the paragraph:
<p class="text_obisnuit">          Lorem Ipsum is simply.</p>

I try this, but isn't working:
FIND: <p class="text_obisnuit">\s+\K(.*?)
Replace by: <p class="text_obisnuit">\1


Ctrl+H
Find what: <p class="text_obisnuit">\s+(?=.*?)
Replace with: <p class="text_obisnuit">
CHECK Wrap around
CHECK Regular expression
UNCHECK . matches newline
Replace all

